# How does AWS service verify the identity of the sender?

Tags: authentication

My question is regarding to :
[How does AWS Secret key and access key work](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68093/how-does-aws-secret-key-and-access-key-work)

The point 5:

> 5. AWS service verifies the identity of the sender and integrity of the message by recomputing the HMAC code.

How does the service verify the identity of the sender?
Does the AWS service know the secrete key? if so how does it get it?